# How to select the second max value from a table by comparing the values among itself

Tags: sql-server

I am working on a project and I need to select maximum value of "Balance" field for each account. But if we have one more rows with opposite sign, we should remove this pair of 2 rows from the search and select the 2nd highest value. Here is an example:

```
Tablet1 (Account varchar(10), Balance money)

A1, 100
A1, 50
A1, -100
A1, 30
```

So the search should return 50 because we have 100 and -100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use `EXCEPT` to remove the opposite pairs then work the usual way with the reamining data.

```
SELECT account, MAX(balance)
FROM (SELECT account, balance
      FROM   table1
      WHERE  balance > 0
      EXCEPT
      SELECT account, -balance
      FROM   table1
      WHERE  balance < 0) data
GROUP BY account
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47ef9/2)</kbd>

`EXCEPT` work the opposite way of `UNION`, removing from the first dataset all the corresponding data in the second dataset.